# count turtles in same patch

Tags: agent, netlogo

I need to do a netlogo program to create the following scenario.

If two turtles come to a single patch they must die and hatch a new turtle with size 2.
How can I do this in netlogo?

My idea is to count the turtles in each patch and if that number is 2 then kill them and hatch new one. Can someone provide me the code to count the turtles in each patch?
Thanks

Comment: We do not provide code. You need to provide the code. We will help after you have done that.

Comment: I have edited the question. Now you can see what I have done. But this is not working. Can u help me now?

Comment: Who gets the marks? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get nicer reading code if you change your breed declaration to:

```
breed [men man]
```

specifying both the plural and the singular forms.

Then, it's:

```
ask patches [
  if count men-here = 2 [
    ask men-here [ die ]
    sprout-men 1 [ set size 2 ]
  ]
]
```